# R irlba sparse data representation

Tags: r

Please let me know if I'm simply doing this wrong...

I have a 47,194 row, 27 column numeric matrix with some missing values. I'm trying to use irlba to factor the matrix. In all previous R projects, I've used NA to indicate missing data. When I do with irlba, I get an error that data is missing. How do I indicate that a value is missing and that irlba should ignore it when factoring the matrix?

Of note: The documentation for irlba doesn't include sparse data. Every element has a value. There are examples with values of zero, but I can't do that because it will factor the value of zero, not ignore the value.

Code example by request:

```
M = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7,8,9), nrow(3))
S = irlba(M,2)
```

I expect irlba to recognize NA as a missing value and ignore it. Instead, it fails and states that M contains a missing value. I've tried null, ., empty value, etc... I believe that there is a special notation for "Ignore this element" that I haven't seen before.

Comment: You were downvoted anonymously, which is a shame since this looks like a valid question. That said, it would still be good if you could post the actual code you’re using — whittled down to a minimal example that exposes the problem. This makes it possible for people to trouble-shoot your problem.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Done. I know that this example is far too small to justify irlba over svd, but the real data set is much larger.

Comment: Maybe better asked on [stats.se]? If `irlba` doesn't provide methods for dealing with missing data, my guess would be that you're looking more at a stats problem (how do I properly deal with this missing data) rather than a programming one?

Comment: @divibisan I scanned questions and answers there and found that SVDmiss performs the same function as irlba, but a little slower. However, it does treat NA as a missing value and ignores it. So, I simply switched form using irlba to SVDmiss and it works now. I'm going to post this as an answer because I've noticed other questions here that are basically asking the same thing: How can I get an SVD if I have missing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using irlba, I found that SVDmiss performs the same function. Given a simple matrix, such as:

```
M = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7,8,9), nrow=3)
```

SVDmiss will give you the SVD and the filled in matrix:

```
S = SVDmiss(M)
```

The SVD is stored in $svd as $u, $d, and $v.

```
S$svd$u
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.4796712  0.77669099  0.4082483
[2,] -0.5723678  0.07568647 -0.8164966
[3,] -0.6650644 -0.62531805  0.4082483
S$svd$d
[1] 1.684810e+01 1.068370e+00 5.039188e-17
S$svd$v
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.2148372 -0.8872307 -0.4082483
[2,] -0.5205874 -0.2496440  0.8164966
[3,] -0.8263375  0.3879428 -0.4082483
```

I can recreate M by multiplying the factors:
    S$svd$u %*% diag(S$svd$d) %*% t(S$svd$v)
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    4    7
    [2,]    2    5    8
    [3,]    3    6    9

But, I don't need to do that because I SVDfill also gives me the imputed/estimated matrix in $Xfill

```
S$Xfill
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

This function is in the package SpatioTemporal. Just in case you haven't installed packages, install the package using:

```
install.package('SpatioTemporal')
```

And then load it when you need it using:

```
library(SpatioTemporal)
```